# Create Dynamic Table On the basis Of 2 Objects

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-soql, pageblocktable

There are 2 objects one obj1 and obj2 I have to create dynamic table in visualforce page in which if new record is inserted to the obj1 then one row should be added to table and if one record in obj2 is inserted then one column should be added to the table.Please guide me to achieve this functionality.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Can you share as to how far have you got till now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public class unitStatusCls{
    public list flrList{get;set;}
    //public list uniList{get;set;}
    public list floorList{get;set;}
    public unitStatusCls(){
        flrList=new list();
        //uniList=new list();
        floorList=new list();
        flrList=[SELECT name, (SELECT name FROM Units__r) FROM Floor__c];
        //system.debug('flrList---------====='+flrList.size());
        //system.debug('uniList---------====='+uniList.size());
    }

```
 public class unitWrapper{
     public Unit__c uni{get;set;}
     public unitWrapper(){
       uni = new Unit__c();
     }
 }
 public class floorWrapper{
    public Floor__c flr{get;set;}
    public list<Unit__c> UniListW{get;set;}
    public floorWrapper(){
       flr = new Floor__c();
       UniListW = new List<Unit__c>();
    }
 }
```

}

VisualForce Page:-

Floors

Comment: How I can Achive this Functionality using wrapper class,Please guide me how I can achive this functionality using wrapper class.

Comment: Please share some of your code so that I can help you accordingly.

Comment: public class unitStatusCls{
    public list<Floor__c> flrList{get;set;}
    public list<Unit__c> uniList{get;set;}
    public unitStatusCls(){
        flrList=new list<Floor__c>();
        uniList=new list<Unit__c>();
        flrList=[SELECT id, Booking__c from Floor__c];
        uniList=[SELECT Booking_Status__c, Block__r.name FROM Unit__c];
        system.debug('flrList---------====='+flrList.size());
        system.debug('uniList---------====='+uniList.size());
    }
}

Comment: I have just started

Comment: @Guru I have update the answer according to your controller.

Comment: I have edited my controller here is my controller and VF page please have a look and let me kow how can I achive it.

Comment: Please share your VF code as well and let me know which variable do you want to be used for rows and which for columns.